# URL Rewrite IIS 7.5 "?" character int the request url

Tags: regex, wcf, iis-7, url-rewriting, web-config

I have a incoming request URL which is:

```
http://localhost/MyService/myservice.svc?serverInfo&pVersion=00
```

I wrote a rule into the webconfig (with the URL Rewrite in IIS Manager):

```
<rule name="ServerInfo" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="myservice[.]svc[\?]serverInfo[&amp;]pVersion[=]([^]+)" />
                    <action type="Redirect" url="myservice.svc/folder/serverInfo/pVersion={R:1}" />
                </rule>
```

But it's not working because i use a **"?"** character in the match url.

How should I change the regular expression to work properly?

(I must make a redirect / rewrite because it's a restful WCF service and it's don't support the type of the incoming url)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this instead:

```
<rule name="ServerInfo" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="myservice.svc" ignoreCase="true" />

  <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
    <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="serverInfo&amp;pVersion=([^]+)" />
  </conditions>

  <action type="Redirect" 
          url="myservice.svc/folder/serverInfo/pVersion={C:1}" 
          appendQueryString="false" 
          redirectType="Found" />
</rule>
```